# Disabling TLS protocols for https:// URLs in git

Tags: git, https, tls

Since my update to Ubuntu 14.04, I cannot connect to the companies git server. It uses https with the SSL protocols only. When running `git clone` (or any other git command that connects to the server) I get the following output:

```
$ git clone https://git.my.company.com/repository.git
Cloning into 'repository'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.my.company.com/repository.git': gnutls_handshake() failed: A record packet with illegal version was received.
```

I had a similar problem with mercurial (same company server), which I 'fixed' by disabling the TLS protocols in the mercurial configuration ~/.hgrc:

```
[ui]
tls = False
```

I suppose I have the same problem with git, but I cannot find out how to disable TLS for git.

As it seems (from the error) that gnutls is used by git. I tried to disable TLS using `gnutls-cli`::

```
$ gnutls-cli "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.0:-VERS-TLS1.1:-VERS-TLS1.2" git.my.company.com
```

This works to establish a connection to the server. Whereas

```
$ gnutls-cli "NORMAL:-VERS-SSL3.0" git.my.company.com
```

gives the same error as git: `GnuTLS error: A record packet with illegal version was received.`

But, there does not seem to be any configuration file (e.g. in /etc/) for gnutls to store the `"NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.0:-VERS-TLS1.1:-VERS-TLS1.2"` part for the hostname

So, how can I configure git or gnutls to disable TLS or to force using SSL?

Note: I am not able to modify the server, the ICT staff has plans to upgrade the server (it is quite out-dated hardware and software wise), but that is (probably) not going to happen soon due to the lack of available time...